# What does the tilde at the end of a file name stand for?

Tags: terminology

In Windows, I believe that files with a tilde in the file name represent files that are currently open in an application. For example, Microsoft Word creates a file with almost the same name as the file you currently have open, but with a tilde in the name. It's icon is also partially faded. As far as I'm aware, this signifies a temporary file that exists

- in case the application crashes and you didn't get a chance to save your file, or
- to allow the original file to remain unlocked by the file system and accessible to other applications.

In Linux, I ran into a *.log file with a tilde at the end of the file name (`scan.log~`). Does that mean the log file is currently open in another application that is potentially writing to it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If a file is appended with a `tilde~`, it only means that it is a backup created by a text editor or similar program; it does not suggest another program is writing to that file. Besides, any file opened in `vi` cannot be opened in another application, but that is another discussion.

To **easily** find all these type of files, type `cd` to get to the top level of your home folder and enter:

```
find -type f -iname '*~'
```

Or, if you want to find them in a specific directory, type:

```
find /home/mike/Downloads -type f -iname '*~'
```

These files can be very useful if you happened to have edited a file and have not saved a backup of the original! `Gedit`, for example, creates such a backup of any file edited, although you can turn off this setting in the preferences. However, the  `(files~)` are **no substitute for a proper backup**, as they might not contain the data you need, or be the version of the edit you wanted.

Comment: Just noting that if the folderset is shared via Samba and then a Windows client's Office software edits a file it will create a hidden file locking metaphor using ~$OriginalFilename.xlsx, for example.  It will contain the necessary information about who has the lock.  So be careful writing scripts to do clean-up work if this is your scenario.

Answer (score 12):

Some text editors (such as `emacs`) create a backup of the file you are editing, and give the backup file the name of the original file plus a tilde.  The file you describe might be the result of opening `scan.log` with such a text editor and making some change.

You can use `fuser` (see Ubuntu package `psmisc`) to see if a process currently has that file open: `fuser scan.log~`