# What is cp command with tilde in final part of destination?

Tags: bash, cp

For example:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list~
```

With this command I not see any changes.
What does the final tilde do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the tilde at the end of a file name stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for)

Comment: Yes, this resolve my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final tilde is just a part of the filename. This command should copy the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` to a new file with the name `/etc/apt/sources.list~`. However, if the second file existed before, it is possible that you don't see any changes.

Comment: Thank you, that file is hidden so I hadn't seen it. Why is it useful to run this command?

Comment: And why did you run it?

Comment: For this topic:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549

Comment: I guess someone just wanted to create a backup copy of ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` file to be able to revert to it later. But I don't know why such a name choice. I would rather use something like ```/etc/apt/sources.list.backup``` or ```/etc/apt/sources.list.save```

Comment: Ah ok, what a fool I am, it was just a name for a preventative backup. xD

Comment: The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.

Comment: I have getted this info from "cp --help".

Comment: That refers to backups made automatically by the ```cp``` command used with ```-b``` or ```--backup``` parameter when the destination file already exists. Eg, if you run ```cp -b somefile.txt otherfile.txt``` and ```otherfile.txt``` already exists, the command will backup it to ```otherfile.txt~``` before copying ```somefile.txt``` over it.