# What is a .txt~ file and how can I open it?

Tags: filesystem, text, nemo

I noticed a file with a `.txt~` extension.

- What does the `~` mean?
- How can I open this file? It seems not to work with a text editor.

Comment: Try to rename the file to SOMETHING.txt and see what happends when you open it with text editor.

Comment: Extensions (.txt) have no required meaning in Ubuntu. A text file can have any name and any extension, or no extension at all. Some file ending in .txt might be a text file...or might not. The system does not care. `~` is sometimes used to represent a backup file, sometimes a working file, sometimes something else.

Comment: Gedit uses that to create a backup.

Comment: It may be an older version of the file with the same name without the `~`.

Comment: @yangmandi That seems to work!

Comment: Related: [What does the tilde at the end of a file name stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for)

Comment: @HuHa’s answer provides the explanation. If you really want to open this backup file, use Gedit, click the open button, navigate to this file, and open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an editor backup file. Many Linux/Unix editors create that when saving the file. It's the same file type as the file without the `~`, so you can use the same program (typically an editor) to open it.

Please notice that on Linux filename extensions don't have the strong semantics that they have on Windows; it's more a convention than anything else. `.txt` is commonly used for text files, but you can give them any extension you like (thus the common `README` name which on Windows would be `README.txt`), so `foo.txt~` can live peacefully side by side to its newer version `foo.txt`.

That's also why there is the `file` command that looks *inside* a file to classify it: Since there is no filename extension for executable files (unlike `foo.exe` on Windows), there is no way of knowing what a file `foo` might be.

Desktop file managers use a MIME type database to classify files by their extensions so they can start the correct application to open them, so it makes sense to follow the convention; but this is not enforced in any way.